# ipv6 kernel module unloaded but my interface has a ipv6 adress

Tags: fedora, ipv6

I try to disable ipv6 on my laptop on fedora 37 by modifying sysctl.conf files:
I first tried to

```
echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf 
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
echo "net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf 
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

This was not working, so I used ansible locally with a bp028 (anssi guide on hardening linux) role i found on the internet and used the ipv6 lines:
first task is to list all .conf files in

```
    - /etc/sysctl.d/
    - /run/sysctl.d/
    - /usr/local/lib/sysctl.d/
    - /usr/lib/sysctl.d
```

Then it comments out net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 and  net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 and then these tasks are run :

```
- name: net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 - disable ipv6
  sysctl:
    name: net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6
    value: '1'
    sysctl_set: yes
    state: present
    reload: yes

- name: net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 - disable ipv6
  sysctl:
    name: net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6
    value: '1'
    sysctl_set: yes
    state: present
    reload: yes
```

Now ipv6 gets disabled correctly when i run the tasks with ansible.

But when i reboot my ipv6 is still active on my ethernet interface when i type `ip a` and i can see traffic in tcpdump on the ipv6 protocol.
When i type `lsmod | grep ipv6` i have only nf_defrag_ipv6
When i type `lsmod | grep ip6` i have only ip6_tables
But chatgpt tells me these modules dont load ipv6 support.
How come my ipv6 is still active and how can i disable it?
Thank you

Comment: First, did you disable in a `/etc/sysctl.d/` file and is there any file in the directory that enables IPv6? I'm assuming that you set both sysctl parameters for IPv6. As a last result, you can add `ipv6.disable=1` to your grub command line.

Comment: ipv6 support could be built-in, so, no module.

Comment: you can completely ignore what ChatGPT says. It's wrong about facts, but it can talk like it was there when the facts were made. In this case, it's right, by accident, though: IPv6 is built-in, not a module. So, instead of asking a chatbot that does know nothing about Linux, how about you tell us what you did to systcl.conf? I don't see immediately what that would have to do with network configuration.

Comment: to disable ipv6, i followed anssi bp028 guide recommending to disable ipv6 at a kernel level (with the lines in the post above). I only asked chatgpt if these ip6_tables and nf_defrag_ipv6 modules were loading ipv6 support
I would like to avoid to have to tweak grub...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is network manager is setting these sysctl config automatically.
To disable it you can do (following this link https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/using-networkmanager-to-disable-ipv6-for-a-specific-connection_configuring-and-managing-networking)

```
nmcli connection modify connection_name ipv6.method "disabled"
nmcli connection up connection_name
```

Or you can use this ansible tasks:

```
- name: retrieve nmcli connection name based on interface 
  shell: nmcli -t connection show | grep {{ var_interface }} | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'
  register: conn_name 

- name: disable ipv6
  community.general.nmcli:
    ifname: enp53s0
    method6: disabled
    conn_name: "{{ conn_name.stdout }}"
    state: present
```